# Can I make a photo follow a number on excel or move it from cell to cell by VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I just finished building a chess game on excel by VBA for my school project.
The way I built it is every piece has a number and a color (Green/Red):

```
1 - Pawn (x16)
2 - King (x2)
3 - Queen (x2)
4 - Bishop (x4)
5 - Night (x4)
6 - Rook (x4)
```

Just so it will look nicer I wanted to add pictures of each piece that will follow the number, Or that will move by a VBA commend that will come with the commend of moving the piece.
I prefer the first option if possible but the second one is good as well.
The way I move the pieces right now is like that:

```
   MoveNum = Range(Range("j2").Value).Value
   Range(Range("j2").Value).Value = 0
   Range(Range("j2").Value).FormulaR1C1 = ""
   Range(Range("j2").Value).Font.Color = -0
   Range(Range("k2").Value).Value = MoveNum
   Range(Range("k2").Value).Font.Color = RGB(210, 0, 0)
```

(This is the one that moves red pieces, the only difference between it and the green is that the RGB is (0, 175, 20) and not  (210, 0, 0)
BTW my entire code is based on the numbers so changing/not using them isn't an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A time-saving alternative could be to use [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) characters, instead of images:

## ♔♕♖♗♘♙♚♛♜♝♞♟

These are Unicode [9812](https://codepoints.net/U+2654) to [9823](https://codepoints.net/U+265F) and you can add them to Excel using either the [`UNICHAR`](https://support.office.com/article/unichar-function-ffeb64f5-f131-44c6-b332-5cd72f0659b8) worksheet function, or the [`ChrW`](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/vb-vba/1565923588/1565923588_ch07-203-fm2xml.html) function in VBA.

Also, you could just **copy and paste them from above**, right into your worksheet, and then manipulate them like you would any other text, including font size.

Here's the knight at 80pt: 
[image: img]

My preferred place to look when I need a symbol or icon is (or to identify one) is **[https://codepoints.net](https://codepoints.net/)**. As of March 2019, Unicode contains almost 140,000 characters, with more being constantly added.
<sub><sup>(Be sure to sign the [petition](https://www.marijuanamommy.com/sign-petition-pot-leaf-emoji/) to have a pot-leaf emoji added!)</sup></sub>

---

If your assignment specifically requires you to use **images** then you can:

- **move the images** with the [`.Top`](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/api/excel.shape.top) and [`.Left`](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/api/excel.shape.left) properties of the [***Shapes* object**](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/api/excel.shape)
- **find the position of the cell** with the [`.Top`](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/api/excel.range.top) and [`.Left`](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/api/excel.range.left) properties of the [***Range* object**](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/api/excel.range(object)).

**Example:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub movePicToCell()
'move the image named "Picture 2" on worksheet "Sheet1" to cell "C3"
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    ws.Shapes("Picture 2").Top = ws.Range("C3").Top
    ws.Shapes("Picture 2").Left = ws.Range("C3").Left
End Sub
```